# How to fill a GridLayout top-to-bottom and then left-to-right?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, grid-layout

The default behavior of a `GridLayout` is that the components are filled row by row, and from left to right. I wonder if I can use it so that the components are filled by columns (from left to right)? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend GridLayout and override just one method
instead of `int i = r * ncols + c;` use `int i = c * nrows + r;` I think that's enough.

```
public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
  synchronized (parent.getTreeLock()) {
    Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
    int ncomponents = parent.getComponentCount();
    int nrows = rows;
    int ncols = cols;
    boolean ltr = parent.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight();

    if (ncomponents == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (nrows > 0) {
        ncols = (ncomponents + nrows - 1) / nrows;
    } else {
        nrows = (ncomponents + ncols - 1) / ncols;
    }
    int w = parent.width - (insets.left + insets.right);
    int h = parent.height - (insets.top + insets.bottom);
    w = (w - (ncols - 1) * hgap) / ncols;
    h = (h - (nrows - 1) * vgap) / nrows;

    if (ltr) {
        for (int c = 0, x = insets.left ; c < ncols ; c++, x += w + hgap) {
        for (int r = 0, y = insets.top ; r < nrows ; r++, y += h + vgap) {
            int i = r * ncols + c;
            if (i < ncomponents) {
            parent.getComponent(i).setBounds(x, y, w, h);
            }
        }
        }
    } else {
        for (int c = 0, x = parent.width - insets.right - w; c < ncols ; c++, x -= w + hgap) {
        for (int r = 0, y = insets.top ; r < nrows ; r++, y += h + vgap) {
            int i = r * ncols + c;
            if (i < ncomponents) {
            parent.getComponent(i).setBounds(x, y, w, h);
            }
        }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that's a terrible idea unless you do the same for `preferredLayoutSize`, `minimumLayoutSize` and so on.

Comment: I don't think so. If you take a look at the calculation you can see that they just calculate max size of component and multiply on rows/cols accordingly.

Comment: @StanislavL: just a follow-up question on this, if i want to make the gridlayout fill the components from the bottom to top (instead of the default top-to-bottom behavior), how should i change the above? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Such use case is not supported by the GridLayout manager.

I suggest you have a look at [`GridBagLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) instead, which allows you to set the location through [`GridBagConstraints.gridx`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#gridx) and [`GridBagConstraints.gridy`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#gridy).

(To get a behavior similar to `GridLayout` be sure to set the weights and fill properly.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve this with a single `GridLayout`.  However, you could have a `GridLayout` of one row that each cell had a `GridLayout` of a single column with several rows.  Although using a different LayoutManager like `TableLayout` might be an easier choice.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com).  You can switch the flow direction with:

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("flowy"));
add(component1);
add(component2);
add(component3, "wrap");
add(component4);
add(component5);
add(component6);
```

There are a many ways to achieve this with MigLayout, and I find it SO much friendlier to use than GridBagLayout and just as capable, if not more so.  You won't need BorderLayout, FlowLayout, BoxLayout, etc. anymore, MigLayout does all that too.

Answer (score 0):

You can just recalculate the position of each component:

```
Int row = ROWS;//amount of ROWS in the grid
Int col = COLUMs;//amount of COLUMS in the grid
Int x = i / row;// i is the component index(0,1,2,3...)
Int y = i - x * row;
Int position=col * x + y;
Panel.add(component, position);//the panel with gridlayout
```

You may need to fill initially the panel in order to avoid a nullPointer on a position that don't exists:

```
For(i=0 to i= ROWS){
For(j =0 to j=columns){
Panel.add(new ...(random component)
}
}
```